# SQLEXCEPTION Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed error insist

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlexception

Hello i need to do 2 active jobs with database in java.Firstly I did with 1 statement but after I read hints in here they said that I should use 2 statement.But although it still get Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed error.

```
try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 }
 catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
      System.err.println("Driver yok");
        return;
 }
 Connection con=null;
    try{
     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kutuphane","root","");
     System.out.println("Veritabnı baglandıldı");
     Statement stmt=con.createStatement();       
     String strSQL="UPDATE emanetler SET IADETARIH='"+strdate+"' WHERE KISIAD='"+jTextField1.getText()+"'    "   
     Statement stmt2=con.createStatement();
     stmt.execute(strSQL);
     ResultSet rs=stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kitaplar");      


while(rs.next()){
    if(rs.getString("KITAPAD").equals(jTextField2.getText())){
        strSQL="UPDATE kitaplar SET KITAPADET="+rs.getInt("KITAPADET")+"+1 WHERE KITAPAD='"+jTextField2.getText()+"'          ";
        stmt2.execute(strSQL);
    }    
}       
            stmt.close();
         stmt2.close();
        }
     catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println("Veritabanı baglanmadi");
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: Looking at your code you need 3 Statement Objects, your `stmt2` object is also getting used in while loop

Comment: Thank you for reply.But I dont understand what do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are using `stmt2` object

```
ResultSet rs=stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kitaplar");
```

Then in while loop

```
strSQL="UPDATE kitaplar SET KITAPADET="+rs.getInt("KITAPADET")+"+1 WHERE KITAPAD='"+jTextField2.getText()+"'          ";
stmt2.execute(strSQL);
```

This must be corrected to use a separate Statement Object in While Loop to execute queries.

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad that helped you.. Have fun coding :)